# Adding foreign key constraint in table vs Alter table adding foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

I have a newbie question here in terms of database design and I've noticed 2 options.
1) include the foreign key constrain in the create table block
2) create table then Alter table by ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY

Appreciate your experienced view on this

Comment: There's no difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. include the foreign key constrain in the create table block
```

self explanatory, You're creating foreign key constraint in create table there are not records.

```
2) create table then Alter table by ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY
```

If you don't have any records in table then this will behave as 1. If you've any records in tables then you need to take care whether the available records doesn't violates the foreign key constraints.